# TIBlob passed through application-level event becomes NULL on the receiving end

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a very simple app where the user selects an image from the iOS photo gallery.

The TIBlob passed to `Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery.success` event is then passed to an application-level event.

The issue is that the TIBlob is NULL when the application level event is received.

Below is a complete code sample.

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({title: 'Camera Test', exitOnClose: true, fullscreen: true, backgroundColor: '#ffffff'});

var bt = Ti.UI.createButton({'title': 'Gallery', top: 10, width: 200, height: 50});
bt.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
            success:function(event) {   
                if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
                    alert(event.media);
                    Ti.App.fireEvent('uploadImage', {image: event.media, source: 'gallery'});
                }else {
                    alert('Image was not uploaded because the type was invalid.');
                }
            },
            cancel:function() {
            },
            error:function(err) {
                alert('Error selecting image from gallery: ' + err);
                Ti.API.error(err);
            },
            allowEditing: false,
            autohide: true,
            mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
      });
});

Ti.App.addEventListener('uploadImage', function(e) {
    alert(e.image);
    alert(e.source);
});

win.add(bt);
win.open();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Appcelerator Guides say that objects passed through and event must be JSON-serializable https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Event+Handling#EventHandling-Firingevents. A TiBlob is not serializable, so I think the blog is not making it through the event.

If this really is a very simple app, I would suggest changing that to a function call instead of firing an event and the blob will be preserved. However, if this absolutely needs to be an event, you could pass `event.media.nativePath` instead and then read a blob out of that when you actually need to do something with it.

Comment: That's excellent to know about event objects having to be JSON-serializable. Thanks!

Comment: On another note, event.media.nativePath throws a "nil string parameter" exception. Any ideas on what that's about?

Comment: It looks like .nativePath is only available when the TiBlob is a Ti.Filesystem.File so I think the event passing method isn't going to work. I'll need to just pass the blob around a different.

Comment: Ah, I see. The doc's didn't really make it clear that the nativePath isn't available. One thing you could do is save the blob to the file system, then you would have a path to work with.